# How to generate same hash value for python 2.7 and 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hash

I have generated a hash for two different function in two different project. One project used python 2.7 environment, other used python 3.4. I need to match those two hash.

```
    x=("asd","def")
    hash(x)
```

It's not matching. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you limited to python's built-in hash function?

Comment: still searching a way via built-in function. If not found the I will go for custom @JoelsElf

Answer (score 3):

Well, tough luck. The internal details of [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) is considered an implementation detail. Additionally, in Pythons since 3.3, the hash function of strings is randomized by default. The calculation differs from 32-bit versions to 64-bit versions (the value is truncated to `Py_ssize_t`).

However, if for example your Python 3.5 is 64-bit and Python 2.7 is 32-bit; you could try anding the Python 3 value with 0xFFFFFFFF to get the 2.7 value, e.g., if

```
>>> hash((1, 2, 3)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

works.

Comment: @SunnoSakib please give the hash values from both python 2 and 3.

Comment: python 3.4 : hash(("asd","def")) ->
-1259920402.....hash(("asd","def")) & 0xFFFFFFFF
3035046894
python 2.7 : hash(("asd","def"))
923829442...hash(("asd","def")) & 0xFFFFFFFF
923829442L

Answer (score 1):

Use [py27hash](https://pypi.org/project/py27hash/) for the same hash results in Python 3 & 2:

```
$ python2.7
>>> print(hash("test1234"))
1724133767363937712

$ python3
>>> print(hash("test1234"))
-2119032519227362575
>>> from py27hash.hash import hash27
>>> print(hash27("test1234"))
1724133767363937712
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deterministally generate hash values using a hash function in `hashlib`:

```py
import hashlib

hash_obj = hashlib.sha256(b"hello")
hex_hash = hash_obj.hexdigest()
print(hex_hash)
# Always prints: 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

There are various kinds of hash functions available in the module, so see more on [the hashlib documention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).